# Codeigniter multidimensional array insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Hello im trying to insert a multidimensional array into mysql using codeigniter. Im having some trouble getting the values to enter correctly.
Here is how the multidimensional array looks

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [A] => FName 2 [B] => LName 2 [C] => PhoneNo 2 [D] => FaxNo 2 ) [3] => Array ( [A] => FName 3 [B] => LName 3 [C] => PhoneNo 3 [D] => FaxNo 3 ) [4] => Array ( [A] => FName 4 [B] => LName 4 [C] => PhoneNo 4 [D] => FaxNo 4 ) [5] => Array ( [A] => FName 5 [B] => LName 5 [C] => PhoneNo 5 [D] => FaxNo 5 ) [6] => Array ( [A] => FName 6 [B] => LName 6 [C] => PhoneNo 6 [D] => FaxNo 6 ) [7] => Array ( [A] => FName 7 [B] => LName 7 [C] => PhoneNo 7 [D] => FaxNo 7 ) [8] => Array ( [A] => FName 8 [B] => LName 8 [C] => PhoneNo 8 [D] => FaxNo 8 ) [9] => Array ( [A] => FName 9 [B] => LName 9 [C] => PhoneNo 9 [D] => FaxNo 9 ) )
```

Here is what i've tried doing

```
function insertfiles($arr_data)
{
    foreach ($arr_data as $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $a){
            $data = array(
                   'Firstname' => $a,
                   'Lastname' => $a,
                   'Phone'=>$a,
                   'Fax' =>$a
                );

                $this->db->insert('test', $data); 
        }
    }
}
```

Im sure im messing this up horribly, it is inserting the values into the database but it's inserting them as follows

since it wont let me upload an image im providing a link to view this image online.
http://psadatadesign.com/img/test-bmp.jpg

any help would be appreciated. As im trying to figure out what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rather your own function

```
function insertfiles($arr_data)
{
    foreach($array_data as $a){
        $data = array(
               'Firstname' => $a['A'],
               'Lastname' => $a['B'],
               'Phone'=>$a['C'],
               'Fax' =>$a['D']
            );

            $this->db->insert('test', $data); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know, if there is any issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases for this one for case 1

If the array you pass does not contain a named key, check the function below

```
$table_array_index_key = array( //if your array does not have a named key.
    0 => array( //first row
        0 => 'first_name 1',
        1 => 'last_name 1',
        2 => 'phone 1',
        3 => 'fax 1'
        ),
    1 => array( //second row
        0 => 'first_name 2',
        1 => 'last_name 2',
        2 => 'phone 2',
        3 => 'fax 2'
        ),
    );

$row = array();
$columns = array();
for($x=0;$x<count($table_array_index_key);$x++){
        $row = array(
            'Firstname' => $table_array_index_key[$x][0], //$table_array[1][0] means table_array row 2 column 1  
            'Lastname' => $table_array_index_key[$x][1],
            'Phone' =>  $table_array_index_key[$x][2],
            'Fax' => $table_array_index_key[$x][3] 
        );
        array_push($columns,$row);
        $rows = array();
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($columns);
```

else if your array contains named keys, check this out.

```
$table_array_index_name = array( //if your array have a named key.
    0 => array( //first row
        'A' => 'first_name 1',
        'B' => 'last_name 1',
        'C' => 'phone 1',
        'D' => 'fax 1'
        ),
    1 => array( //second row
        'A' => 'first_name 2',
        'B' => 'last_name 2',
        'C' => 'phone 2',
        'D' => 'fax 2'
        ),
    );

$rows = array();
$columns = array();
$arrayNames = array('A','B','C','D'); 
for($x=0;$x<count($table_array_index_name);$x++){
        $row = array(
            'Firstname' => $table_array_index_name[$x][$arrayNames[0]], //note $arrayNames[0] = A
            'Lastname' => $table_array_index_name[$x][$arrayNames[1]],
            'Phone' =>  $table_array_index_name[$x][$arrayNames[2]],
            'Fax' => $table_array_index_name[$x][$arrayNames[3]] 
        );
        array_push($columns,$row);
        $rows = array();
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($columns);
```

For which you can loop further like this one:

```
$table_array_index_name = array( //if your array have a named key.
    0 => array( //first row
        'A' => 'first_name 1',
        'B' => 'last_name 1',
        'C' => 'phone 1',
        'D' => 'fax 1'
        ),
    1 => array( //second row
        'A' => 'first_name 2',
        'B' => 'last_name 2',
        'C' => 'phone 2',
        'D' => 'fax 2'
        ),
    );

$rows = array();
$columns = array();
$arrayNames = array('A','B','C','D');
$dbFieldName = array('Firstname','Lastname','Phone','Fax');
for($x=0;$x<count($table_array_index_name);$x++){
    for($y=0;$y<count($arrayNames);$y++){
        $row[$dbFieldName[$y]] = $table_array_index_name[$x][$arrayNames[$y]];
    }
        array_push($columns,$row);
        $rows = array();
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($columns);
```

which will return the following data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => first_name 1
            [Lastname] => last_name 1
            [Phone] => phone 1
            [Fax] => fax 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => first_name 2
            [Lastname] => last_name 2
            [Phone] => phone 2
            [Fax] => fax 2
        )

)
```

Personally I prefer the for loop because we can have more freedom and control when manipulating arrays.

For the $this->db->insert_batch function, please check out the code igniter active record documentation:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html